# JWT secret part from php password_hash() (128bit random salt and password hashed together)?

Tags: php, jwt

We are using JWT (Json Web Token), with HS256 algorithm.
Is it ok to use PHP's password_hash() functions output for the secret part?
It's output is a 128 bit random salt with the user's password hashed together with bcrypt.

(the reason we want this, is that we have two separate systems sharing a common database.
Sharing a common secret would be not very practical, and we need to access that database record anyway, since we need to check if the user is active or not)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why or even *how* you'd try to do that, but I'm pretty sure it's a bad idea.

1. JWTs don't *have* a "secret part". Every part of a JWT is public information (you *can* encrypt them but if you're relying on that to add any security, there is probably something wrong with your design).
2. JWTs are signed (sometimes with an asymmetric signature, sometimes with a MAC) using a key. HS256 means using HMAC-SHA2-256, which uses a symmetric key. This key must be kept secret from the user and any other third party, and must be known to both the issuer and verifier of the JWT, but is not part of the JWT.
3. What are you even planning to use as the inputs to the `password_hash` function? The entire JWT header + payload (body)? That would typically be too long for the default password hashing function (bcrypt), and also would provide **absolutely no security** because anybody could generate their own forged tokens for arbitrary users with valid bcrypt "signatures". Or are you planning to use the user's actual password? That would provide no protection against an attacker modifying the JWT, e.g. to make it last forever unless you concatenated it with the actual JWT to sign, and also require checking the user's password every time the JWT is verified (eliminating the scaling advantage of using JWTs instead of secure random tokens). It would also prevent refreshing the JWT, meaning they couldn't securely be issued except for very short sessions (JWTs can't be revoked easily, so they need to be very short-lived).
4. Or were you planning to use the JWT signing key - the one that should have been used in HMAC-SHA2-256 - as the input to `password_hash`? That provides no protection against tampering with or forging the JWT, unless you concatenated the key with the JWT itself before hashing (which would hit the length limit). It's also phenomenally wasteful; just use HMAC the way the JWT standard says to.
5. Password hashing is - by design, for security reasons - very slow due to being highly computationally expensive. This applies both on generating and verifying password hashes. You'll crush your own server under a self-inflicted denial-of-service attack if you try to validate a password hash on every single authenticated request. However, the security reasons for password hashing to be slow don't apply to JWTs (to the extremely limited sense that the question even makes sense; neither JWTs nor their signing keys are user-selected memorized secrets the way passwords are), so you shouldn't be using a password hashing algorithm with one anyhow.
6. You'll completely break compatibility with any standards-compliant JWT library, unless you're proposing to generate the key for each JWT using `password_hash` (and where are you getting the user's password after the initial login?), in which case it'll just be incredibly slow and make extremely concerning claims about your password storage. Rolling your own implementation of authentication and session management code is not a great idea if you don't understand what you're dealing with, and a terrible idea if you're trying something like this.

As a side note:

> we need to access that database record anyway, since we need to check if the user is active or not

You have missed the point of JWTs. That check should be performed once at login, and again every few minutes when the JWT expires and the user tries to refresh it, and not at any other time. If the user is deactivated while logged in, their access will end when their JWT expires (hopefully in a single-digit number of minutes) and can't be refreshed. The rest of the time, you don't even touch that DB table.

If you need to check the DB for the user's account status on every request, you can (and should) just issue opaque, cryptographically-secure random session tokens and store those (or their hash, using a fast secure hash like a member of the SHA2 or SHA3 family) in the DB. Checking the DB for live session token can replace or happen alongside checking for the user's active status (and anything else, like permissions) on each request, at no extra cost, in a considerably simpler and arguably more secure system.

Comment: I think i was not clear enough. Sorry for the misunderstanding. JWTs are signed with a key. That is what i called the secret part. And my idea was that we could use the database field where we store the user's password hashed. A big drawback is that a database read access would give the ability to generate any user's JWT token.

Comment: Yeah that's just storing plaintext-equivalent passwords, rather than literally plaintext ones; don't do that. Still totally misses the point of JWTs too; if you require a DB lookup on every request to get a user-specific symmetric key, you're strictly better off using random opaque tokens than using JWTs.